# How can I solve $(z-3i)^2 = 2i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried hours to solve this equation:

$$(z-3i)^2 = 2i$$

but I cannot figure it out. Of course, Wolframalpha gives me the solution but I'd like to know how to solve it by hand.

Comment: Can you include what you've written down so far?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get rid of $z^1$?

Comment: The square is already completed, so there is nothing more to get rid of on the LHS. All that's left to do is figure out $(2i)^{1/2}$.

Comment: that would be 6 papers to scan @TheCount

Comment: @kimsay then how about just typing the relevant parts?

Comment: when I multiply it out then there is a single z left which is uncomfortable

Comment: kimsay, you can do it that way by using quadratic formula. But it is unnecessary (see Bernard's answer).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

First calculate the square roots of $2i$ (you can guess or use the exponential form of $2i$).

Answer (score 1):

- How about try something simpler first? Solve $w^2=i$, which is equivalent to find $r$ and $\theta$ such that 
  $$
  (re^{i\theta})^2=e^{i\pi/2}.
  $$
- Then try to solve $w^2=2i$ by noting that this is nothing but
  $$
  \big(\frac{w}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2=i.
  $$
- I'm sure you can see your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

First way: quadratic formula

$$z^2-6iz-9=2i\implies x^2-6iz-(9-2i)=0\implies$$

$$\Delta=(6i)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-(9-2i))=-36+36-8i=-8i=\left[(1+i)^{5/2}\right]^2\implies$$

$$z_{1,2}=\frac{6i\pm\sqrt\Delta}2$$

Second way: comparing real and imaginary parts: put $\;z=x+iy\; $ , so

$$z^2-6iz-9=2i\implies \begin{cases}x^2-y^2+6y-9=0\\{}\\-6x=2i\end{cases}\implies x=-\frac13i\implies$$

$$\implies-\frac19-y^2+6y-9=0\;\;\cdots\text{ and etc.}$$

Answer (score 0):

We start with

$$2i=(a+bi)^2=a^2-b^2+2abi$$

We know the real part must be zero, hence

$$0=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)\implies a=\pm b$$

Plugging this into the equation we get from the imaginary parts:

$$ab=1\implies\pm a^2=1\implies a=\pm1\implies b=\pm1$$

After appropriately checking signs, we end up with

$$2i=(1+i)^2=(-1-i)^2$$

Can you take it from there?